# functions in <locale> missing - islower() and isupper()

Tags: c, echo, locale, yacc, lex

I am trying to do a compiler using lex and yacc, but for some reason the code does not work in my VM machine in my MAC because it says that there are some functions missing from the header . Those functions are, islower() and isupper(). ECHO and yylex for some reason are also missing. I have uninstalled and installed both bison and flex for lex and yacc, but nothing fixed it.

The same code works fine in my VM machine in a Windows computer. So my code is not the problem. 
Here is the error[image: error caused with functions missing]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text terminals.

Comment: For the islower part, you simply forgot to include <ctypes.h>.

Comment: I included ctypes and it says: no such file or directory. that might be the problem. how do I fix it?

Comment: Ctype, not ctypes. Read `man islower`

Comment: thank you :) but I still need the other two :(

Comment: Do a search through all the library headers? That would certainly have told you where `isupper` and `islower` are.

Comment: If library is really present , sometimes changing the position of `#include <ctype.h>` line might work. Include it at the start.

Comment: yyerror and yylex should be created automatically by bison and they are not being created. Howcome?

Comment: You'll have to look at the code generated by Yacc (or Bison) to see whether it declares `yylex()` and `yyerror()`.  Are the lines of code referenced in stuff you wrote or in boilerplate written by Yacc?  If the latter, there seems to be a bug — which version of which Yacc variant are you using?  If it is in stuff you wrote, especially if it comes before the first `%%` line, then it could be that the functions are not yet declared.  Either move your code after the second `%%` line or declare the functions — but be careful about how you declare the functions; moving the code is likely better.

Answer (score 1):

1. `islower` and `isupper` are found in `<ctype.h>`, not in `<locale.h>`. It is possible that some non-standard-conformant C library implementation provides a `locale.h` which also includes `ctype.h`, but that is certainly not the case with the standard C installation on Mac OS X (or, for that matter, Linux).
2. It is your responsibility to write `yyerror`; you must also provide an accurate prototype in any file in which it is called. It will be called automatically by the yacc/bison-generated parser, but yacc/bison does not put any particular requirements on the `yyerror` prototype. It can return any type, or none, since the yacc/bison-generated parser never uses the return value. And it can be a varargs function if you want to write a version which does some kind of printf-style interpolation. You'll also need to declare it in any other translation union which makes use of it (as your lexer apparentely does).
3. `yylex` is not automatically declared by the yacc/bison-generated grammar either, although it is called and is expected to return an `int`. With a bison-generated parser, the precise arguments provided to `yylex` (and `yyerror`) depend on a variety of bison declarations; in particular, if you specify that the lexer is reentrant, bison will provide additional arguments. In the simplest case (with no bison declarations), the prototype should be

   ```
   int yylex(void);
   ```

   which matches the `yylex` generated by lex/flex (again, without any reentrancy declarations).

   In traditional C, the declaration above would not be necessary, since `int` is the default return type for undeclared functions and the lack of arguments in the call matches the lack of arguments in the definition. However, modern C compilers (such as clang, as found on OS X, and/or gcc) will warn you about missing prototypes even if the code would work anyway. It is highly recommended that you include explicit declarations, as mentioned by the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Grammar-Layout.html#Grammar-Layout): (section 1.9, emphasis added)

   > The prologue may define types and variables used in the actions. You can also use preprocessor commands to define macros used there, and use `#include` to include header files that do any of these things. **You need to declare the lexical analyzer `yylex` and the error printer `yyerror` here,** along with any other global identifiers used by the actions in the grammar rules.
4. I don't know where you get the impression that the compiler is complaining about `ECHO`, unless it is the misplaced caret; the error text clearly states that the problem is with `yyerror`. The caret is in the wrong place because the line being shown is the source line in your lexical definition file, whereas the line the C compiler is actually complaining about is the line generated by flex, which does not include the pattern `.` and is therefore spaced slightly differently.

   That's a weakness in clang's mechanism for using carets to show you the *precise* location of the error, but I think you'll agree that on the whole it is a lot more friendly to show you the original source line with its corresponding line number.